# Create a folder if it doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9

Create a folder if it doesn't exist in Magento, I don't want to use mkdir(). Is there any way to do this ? May be core_file_uploader can work out, but its throwing error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Magento has `Varien_Io_File` class for quite many filesystem works.**

So instead of using PHP's vanilla `mkdir()` function, you can use the Magento's way:

```
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->mkdir(your_path_to_dir);
```

Or you can also check if the directory does not exist right before creating it

```
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
if (!$io->fileExists(your_path_to_dir, false)) {
    $io->mkdir(your_path_to_dir);
}
```